# Move around dynamic divs in blog post listings

Tags: javascript, css, each

I am working with a blog and want to move the category above the title on each post listing. when I use the following code I get 50 clones of the first category. I think I need to be using the index parameter of `.each()` but I'm not sure. Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".blog-category").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).insertBefore( jQuery(".blog-head") ) ;
    });
});
```

Essentially I'm trying to insert the

```
.blog-category
```

before the

```
.blog-head
```

on each post.

**HTML**

```
<div id="entry-2839">
    <div class="blog-post-in">
        <div class="blog-head">content</div>
        <div class="blog-side">
            <div class="blog-category">more content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTML?

Comment: `<div id="entry-2839">   
    <div class="blog-post-in">  
       <div class="blog-head">"xyzcontent"</div>  
    <div class="blog-side">  
        <div class="blog-category"> "morecontent"</div>  
    </div>  
</div>  
</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var e = jQuery(this);
e.closest(".blog-post-in").prepend(e);
```

Comment: worked. thanks a lot. sry for my lackluster html formatting in comment.